# Convert Int data type to date

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, datetime

The SQL server database I'm using has a field stored as an integer but it is a date. Currently it is showing `20191012`. I've tried the below and it seems to convert it but I'd like to show it in 10/12/2019 format. Thanks.

```
CONVERT(DATE,CONVERT(VARCHAR(20),EFFDAT)) AS DATE_EFF
```

Comment: Date and time datatypes don't have a format; they are binary values. If you want it to **display** in a specific format, you need to do that in your *display layer* (aka your application).

Comment: If the actual data type of the column is 'int', and the 'int' is stored as a number that corresponds to YYYYMMDD, then yes, that is the way to convert it to an actual 'date' format for storing. Which is, of course, completely different from a DISPLAY format.

Comment: Personally, I feel the real question is: Why are you storing dates as an `int` in the first place?

Comment: I have no say in why it is stored that way unfortunately. How can I change the format though? When I run the code above it makes it "2019-10-12".

Comment: Yes you can display it in another format. Google how to display a DateTime using SQL. You'll find hundreds of examples already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
DECLARE @myint int = 20191012

SELECT CAST(CAST(@myint as char(8)) as date) AS [theDate]
SELECT CONVERT(char(10), (CAST(CAST(@myint as char(10)) as date)), 101) AS [theDateStyleString]
```

Is one way, where the first query simply casts the data to the date datatype and the second query additionally converts to a string with the MM/DD/YYYY format.  But understand that converting to a string is not the same as keeping the date datatype- since date functions and comparisons (>, <, etc) do not work correctly on strings.

This produces output:

```
theDate
----------
2019-10-12


theDateStyleString
------------
10/12/2019
```

Answer (score 1):

You first need to convert the *number* `20191012` to a date:

```
SELECT DATEFROMPARTS(
           20191012 / 10000,
           20191012 % 10000 / 100,
           20191012 % 100
       )
-- 2019-10-12 (DATE)
```

Then `FORMAT` it:

```
SELECT FORMAT(DATEFROMPARTS(
           20191012 / 10000,
           20191012 % 10000 / 100,
           20191012 % 100
       ), 'MM/dd/yyyy')
-- 10/12/2019 (NVARCHAR)
```

The easier way is to convert the number to a string and do a couple of `SUBSTRING()`s.